# I created a channel, but I can't get the id of this created channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I created a channel using the code below, but I can't find the channel ID to continue with the function that moves to the category and sends a message to it.

```
const buyid = createID

message.guild.createChannel(`venda-${buyid}`, 'text', [
    {
        id: message.guild.defaultRole.id,
        deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
    {
        id: userID,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
])
```

Comment: Its not clear what youre asking, are there additional details you left out? Maybe an error message or what you expect from the code?

Comment: I'll try to explain. I am creating the text channel using this code but I don't know how to get the id of this channel I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do futher things with a created channel when you do this:

```
message.guild.createChannel(`venda-${buyid}`, 'text', [
    {
        id: message.guild.defaultRole.id,
        deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
    {
        id: userID,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
]).then((channel) => {

 channel.setParent("PARENT_CHANNEL_ID")
 channel.send("YOUR_MESSAGE")

})
```